# Queries hung for no specific reason

Tags: mysql

I'm having a strange issues for the past few days. I run data updates at night that shouldn't take more than a few hours.

Several weeks ago a single script took two days to complete. I ran it again when the server wasn't processing anything and it took minutes.

I figured this is some kind of race condition, or something triggered when the server load is high.

It is indeed reproduced every night, but not on the same step. I mean I update a lot of databases that are similarly processed. It won't fail on the same database every night, but it will fail on the same specific query.

Here's the specific query:

```
create temporary table trip_types (
    id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    stops_taken varchar(32) not null default '',
    index trip_type_idx (stops_taken)
)
select (
    select md5(group_concat(st.stop_iid))
    from stop_times st
    where st.trip_iid = t.id
    group by st.trip_iid
    order by st.stop_sequence
) as stops_taken
from trips t
group by stops_taken;

update trips t
set trip_type = (
    select id
    from trip_types
    where stops_taken = (
        select md5(group_concat(stop_iid))
        from stop_times
        where trip_iid = t.id
        group by trip_iid
        order by stop_sequence asc
    )
    group by stops_taken
);
```

Basically a `trip` is a collection of `stops` (+ time of departure, hence `stop_times`), ordered by `stop.stop_sequence`. I want to compare identical trips regardless of the time of departure, hence I'm comparing the ordered list of stops taken.

My goal is to have an `INT` in the `trips` table that would indicate the trip type (list of trips taken), so that I can differentiate trips just using the `INT` column:

- take one trip
- compute list of stops taken
- save as md5 in a temp table
- once all trips are computed, put back the ID of the temp table in the `trips` table

So my script does this in two steps: compute md5 and store in temp table, then fill back into `trips`.

I had an optimized query for computing the md5, however my SQL client crashed and destroyed my work :) I'll have to do it again. I'm just saying, because I think there is room for improvement in these queries.

Now I have read some documentation here and there, including [this blog post](https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/01/19/looking-deeper-innodbs-problem-many-row-versions/) that describes an issue that is very similar to mine.

I have plotted similar graphs from my server, here's one occurrence:

[image: Graphs showing InnoDB counters]

As you can see there is a very intense use of Pool requests, as well as MySQL handler read next. As [the doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Handler_read_rnd_next) says, either my query or my table design is poor:

> The number of requests to read the next row in the data file. This value is high if you are doing a lot of table scans. Generally this suggests that your tables are not properly indexed or that your queries are not written to take advantage of the indexes you have.

Here's the `trips` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `trips` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `trip_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `trip_headsign` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trip_short_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `route_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `route_iid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `service_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `trip_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `direction_id` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `block_id` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shape_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shape_iid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wheelchair_accessible` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bikes_allowed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `trip_id_UNIQUE` (`trip_id`),
  KEY `direction_id` (`direction_id`),
  KEY `block_id` (`block_id`),
  KEY `shape_id` (`shape_id`),
  KEY `route_iidx` (`route_iid`),
  KEY `trip_type_idx` (`trip_type`),
  KEY `trip_shape_idx` (`shape_iid`),
  CONSTRAINT `trip_route_id` FOREIGN KEY (`route_iid`) REFERENCES `routes` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `trip_shape` FOREIGN KEY (`shape_iid`) REFERENCES `shapes` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Here's the `stop_times` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `stop_times` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `arrival_time` time NOT NULL,
  `arrival_time_seconds` int(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idep` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hour` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `departure_time` time NOT NULL,
  `departure_time_seconds` int(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stop_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `stop_iid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `stop_sequence` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `stop_headsign` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pickup_type` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `drop_off_type` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shape_dist_traveled` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trip_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `trip_iid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timepoint` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`hour`),
  KEY `stop_iidx` (`stop_iid`),
  KEY `trip_iidx` (`trip_iid`),
  KEY `idep_idx` (`idep`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (hour)
(PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (1) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 ... truncated for clarity... you get the idea ...
 PARTITION p29 VALUES LESS THAN (30) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p30 VALUES LESS THAN (1000) ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

I have worked on these, I think they're good. If you see something stupid, please point it out!

As per the query, here's the temp table `select`:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: t
   partitions: NULL
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: direction_id
      key_len: 2
          ref: NULL
         rows: 30065
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
        table: st
   partitions: p0,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10,p11,p12,p13,p14,p15,p16,p17,p18,p19,p20,p21,p22,p23,p24,p25,p26,p27,p28,p29,p30
         type: ref
possible_keys: trip_iidx
          key: trip_iidx
      key_len: 4
          ref: t.id
         rows: 22
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Here's the `update`:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: UPDATE
        table: t
   partitions: NULL
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 30065
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
        table: trip_types
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: trip_type_idx
          key: trip_type_idx
      key_len: 34
          ref: func
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using index
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 3
  select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
        table: stop_times
   partitions: p0,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10,p11,p12,p13,p14,p15,p16,p17,p18,p19,p20,p21,p22,p23,p24,p25,p26,p27,p28,p29,p30
         type: ref
possible_keys: trip_iidx
          key: trip_iidx
      key_len: 4
          ref: dbname.t.id
         rows: 22
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

What's weird is that currently the server is failing hard and it will be stuck for hours. However if I kill the query and stop the script; then run the query again it will be gone much faster:

1. Identify the query

   ```
   *************************** 62. row ***************************
          Id: 1460
        User: johndoe
        Host: foobar:46842
          db: xxxyyyzzz
     Command: Query
        Time: 3365
       State: Sending data
        Info: create temporary table trip_types (
         id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
         stops_tak
   ```
2. Kill it

   ```
   mysql> kill 1460;
   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
   ```
3. <strike>Do it again, by hand:</strike>

   This block is invalid, as it is related to my mistake in the query. Please see edits of this question to fully understand.

   I didn't have any new occurrence so I can't run it again to see how fast it is. What's sure, is it's faster.

   Also, on the next occurrence I'll try the explain on the active query, to see what exactly happens. Stay tuned! :)

   ```
   mysql> truncate stop_connections;</strike>
   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.95 sec)

   mysql> insert into stop_connections (from_stop_iid, to_stop_iid, distance)
       -> select s.id as sid, d.id as did, pow(s.stop_lat - d.stop_lat, 2) + pow(s.stop_lon - d.stop_lon, 2) as distance
       -> from stops s, stops d
       -> where d.id <> s.id
       -> having distance < 0.00000683497
       -> on duplicate key update from_stop_iid = from_stop_iid;
   Query OK, 15172 rows affected (50.04 sec)
   Records: 15172  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
   ```

Fifty seconds. It was stuck for about an hour, but ran manually it was done in seconds.

From my various reading online, here are the customisations I made to `my.cnf`:

```
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860111/warning-a-long-semaphore-wait
innodb_adaptive_hash_index = 0

# https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=59047 comment [1 Mar 2011 23:47] James Day
# https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html
query_cache_size = 0

# http://stackoverflow.com/a/414934/334493
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
```

Each parameter is documented with SO question/answer, bug or links to the MySQL doc.

As you can see from said linked question, I've also had a lot of crashes. I've monitored the result of `show status like 'Uptime'`:

[image: MySQL server uptime plotted]

The server crashes a lot. At least once a day. It seems it gets stuck on semaphores, and gives up waiting and crashes itself. Here are extracts from `/var/log/mysql/error.log` ()

```
--Thread 140522828371712 has waited at buf0flu.cc line 1198 for 799.00 seconds the semaphore:
--Thread 140522828371712 has waited at buf0flu.cc line 1198 for 807.00 seconds the semaphore:
--Thread 140522828371712 has waited at buf0flu.cc line 1198 for 827.00 seconds the semaphore:
--Thread 140522828371712 has waited at buf0flu.cc line 1198 for 830.00 seconds the semaphore:
--Thread 140522828371712 has waited at buf0flu.cc line 1198 for 847.00 seconds the semaphore:
--Thread 140522828371712 has waited at buf0flu.cc line 1198 for 861.00 seconds the semaphore:
--Thread 140522828371712 has waited at buf0flu.cc line 1198 for 867.00 seconds the semaphore:
--Thread 140522828371712 has waited at buf0flu.cc line 1198 for 887.00 seconds the semaphore:
--Thread 140522828371712 has waited at buf0flu.cc line 1198 for 892.00 seconds the semaphore:
--Thread 140522828371712 has waited at buf0flu.cc line 1198 for 907.00 seconds the semaphore:
--Thread 140522828371712 has waited at buf0flu.cc line 1198 for 923.00 seconds the semaphore:
--Thread 140522828371712 has waited at buf0flu.cc line 1198 for 927.00 seconds the semaphore:
--Thread 140522828371712 has waited at buf0flu.cc line 1198 for 947.00 seconds the semaphore:
```

Or:

```
2015-10-10T01:23:43.993606Z 0 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Semaphore wait has lasted > 600 seconds. We intentionally crash the server because it appears to be hung.
2015-10-11T01:53:16.961205Z 0 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Semaphore wait has lasted > 600 seconds. We intentionally crash the server because it appears to be hung.
2015-10-11T13:48:43.767908Z 0 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Semaphore wait has lasted > 600 seconds. We intentionally crash the server because it appears to be hung.
2015-10-12T01:42:34.522508Z 0 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Semaphore wait has lasted > 600 seconds. We intentionally crash the server because it appears to be hung.
2015-10-12T04:37:18.720553Z 0 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Semaphore wait has lasted > 600 seconds. We intentionally crash the server because it appears to be hung.
```

In the hours/minutes before self destruction, the server dumps `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`, which I failed to interpret. I just see that it's waiting for semaphores created at various places in the code. I've had a look at the source code but I don't have the knowledge to understand what's going on.
Here are the code lines that generated most of the semaphore waits (1st number is number of occurrences):

```
9656 buf0flu.cc:1062
1381 trx0undo.cc:1778
1115 buf0flu.cc:1198
 832 dict0boot.ic:36
 792 srv0srv.cc:2000
 544 dict0dict.cc:1089
 517 row0ins.cc:1791
```

It seems that `buf0flu.cc:1062` would be the #1 hang generator. Well, I don't know what to do with that :)

So here's my issue. I've been wondering and thinking what I did wrong and what I could do to fix this, but now I'm stuck.

Any ideas?

---

SW: Debian 8, Linux 3.16.0, MySQL 5.7.8-rc-log
HW: HP MicroServer ProLiant G8, Intel Celeron 1610T, 2GB RAM, System on 850 EVO SSD and Database on Seagate 2TB hard drive.

MySQL `tmpdir` is on a 384MB ramdisk, which once was filled with temptables (and no space left on device). I considered using the SSD as the tmpdir. I'm not sure it is relevant here.

---

Clarifications about the table schema / application flow.

Three tables are chained: `trips`, `stop_times` and `stops`.

- a `stop` is basically an ID and lat/lon
- a `stop_time` is a `stop` + a timestamp, say 11am
- a `trip` is a collection of `stop_times`, chained by `stop_sequence`

So if I have 4 stops: `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`, I could have many `stop_times`:

- `stop_time` #1: `A` at 11am
- `stop_time` #2: `A` at 11:05am
- `stop_time` #3: `A` at 11:10am
- `stop_time` #4: `B` at 11:06am
- `stop_time` #5: `C` at 11:07am
- `stop_time` #6: `D` at 11:08am

I could have several trips like this:

- trip #1: uses `stop_times` #1, #4, #5 and #6 (stops ABCD starting at 11am)
- trip #2: uses `stop_times` #1 and #6 (stops AD starting at 11am)
- trip #3: uses `stop_times` #2, #7, #8... (stops ABCD starting at 11:05am)
- etc

I want to identify identical trips in terms of stops taken. Here, trips #1 and #3 share the same stop sequence: ABCD. Trip #2 uses the same path from A to D, however it's not the same trip type because it doesn't make the stops at B and C.

---

I have done some benchmarking to improve the query: create an external (non temp) table to store a mapping between trip IDs and trip types (`group_concat` of used stops)

1. Store trip ID + trip type as is, in a `text` field (sequence of stops: `1,543,343,394,10,...`)
2. Store trip ID + trip type as md5 of the stops sequence, in a `char(32)`

When used by the application, the trip typed is used in a `group by` statement. Joining the external table and grouping made the performance drop by a factor of 5x to 10x.

I have successfully optimized the trip type generation though, by computing the stop sequence only once:

1. Add a column `stops_taken` to `trips` as a `text` or a `char(32)` (depending on the risk of md5 collision)
2. Fill this column
3. Fill a temp table with these values to generate IDs (auto increment)
4. Put back the trip type ID in the `trips` table.

Here's the new script:

```
update trips t
set stops_taken = (
  select md5(group_concat(stop_iid))
  from stop_times
  where trip_iid = t.id
  group by trip_iid
  order by stop_sequence asc
);
create temporary table trip_types (
    id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    stops_taken char(32) not null,
    key st (stops_taken)
);
insert into trip_types(stops_taken) select distinct stops_taken from trips;
update trips t join trip_types tt on tt.stops_taken = t.stops_taken
set t.trip_type = tt.id;
```

On one DB, this reduces the execution time from ~32-40s to ~23s. That's a nice ~35% drop.

---

I could reproduce the issue with this new script. Handler read next counter went up like crazy and it's been stuck on the query for more than 10 minutes now.

I saw that while this is not normal, this doesn't necessarily crash the server. What does is the rise of the semaphore wait time counter: see the rise causing a crash (the 11pm restart of mysql was mine):

[image: Correlation between semaphore wait time counter and server crashes]

For now this counter is 0 so I'm not risking any mysql crash. However it is stuck, and thanks to @jkavalik suggestion, I could see what is the query causing it:

```
update trips t
set stops_taken = (
  select md5(group_concat(stop_iid))
  from stop_times
  where trip_iid = t.id
  group by trip_iid
  order by stop_sequence asc
);
```

So that's indeed the md5/stop sequence generation.

What puzzles me is if I'm doing the same query without updating the trips table, it goes nicely:

```
mysql> select t.id, tt.*
    -> from
    -> trips t
    -> left join (
    ->   select trip_iid, md5(group_concat(stop_iid))
    ->   from stop_times
    ->   group by trip_iid
    ->   order by stop_sequence asc
    -> ) tt on tt.trip_iid = t.id;
+-------+----------+----------------------------------+
| id    | trip_iid | md5(group_concat(stop_iid))      |
+-------+----------+----------------------------------+
|     1 |        1 | 06e9d5dbd52703144d4244c6720cdeb2 |
|     2 |        2 | 6e6b7899a4668bf0a0c88e07d9adc337 |
|     3 |        3 | 6e6b7899a4668bf0a0c88e07d9adc337 |
...
| 11726 |    11726 | adebbf5bb888e38fb55a97b5a9c83763 |
| 11728 |    11728 | 1b76be03f1202110f62c74e6ddac2119 |
+-------+----------+----------------------------------+
11729 rows in set (2.79 sec)
```

Finished in less than 3 seconds. The other query is still stuck, now it's been stuck for 15 minutes.

Comment: The `order by st.stop_sequence` is redundant. Have you tried removing it?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that both the md5 function and the group_concat function are very slow. So, you should probably avoid calculating them twice. Unfortunately this work-around involves an additional temporary table.

As I assume that you'll be either computing this periodically or on a trigger any time there's a "real" update to trips, and as I suspect the trip_type_idx is leading to stalls during your script propagation you may want to drop the key entirely. That way it won't be recomputed halfway through your updates. By the same token, you'll also want to destroy any foreign keys that point to this field.

```
ALTER TABLE trips DROP KEY trip_type_idx;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE trans_trip_types (
    trip_id         unsigned    not null primary key,
    md5_stops_taken varchar(32) not null,
    INDEX           idx_md5 (md5_stops_taken)
)
  SELECT st.trip_iid AS trip_id,
         md5(Group_Concat(DISTINCT st.stop_iid ORDER BY st.stop_sequence)) AS md5_stops_taken
    FROM stop_times AS st
    JOIN trips t
      ON st.trip_iid = t.id
GROUP BY st.trip_iid;

create temporary table trip_types (
    id          int unsigned autonumber not null primary key, -- back to autonumber
    stops_taken varchar(32)             not null default '',
    INDEX       trip_type_idx (stops_taken)
)
SELECT DISTINCT md5_stops_taken AS stops_taken
FROM trans_trip_types ORDER BY md5_stops_taken;

UPDATE trips AS t
    SET t.trip_type = 
      (SELECT tt.id
         FROM trans_trip_types AS ttt
         JOIN trip_types AS tt
           ON tt.stops_taken = ttt.stops_taken 
        WHERE ttt.trip_iid = t.trip_iid
        LIMIT 1
      );

DROP trans_trip_types;

ALTER TABLE trips ADD KEY trip_type_idx (trip_type);
```

As [jkavalik](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/64556/jkavalik) points out, you cannot simply `ENABLE` and `DISABLE` keys (e.g. `ALTER TABLE trips DISABLE KEYS`) for InnoDB tables in MySQL, but index re-creation should be faster than updating indexes one at a time.

Misquoting the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) ever so slightly

> [InnoDB] does this with a special algorithm [`fast index creation` as of 
>   MySQL version 5.7] that is much faster than inserting keys one by one. 
>   Using ALTER TABLE ... [ADD KEY] requires the INDEX privilege in addition 
>   to the privileges mentioned earlier.

Comment: **Comments are not for extended discussion**; this conversation has been **[moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30216/discussion-on-answer-by-mpag-queries-hung-for-no-specific-reason)**. Please use that facility if you need to continue the dialogue.

Comment: InnoDB does NOT support `DISABLE KEYS`. But creating the key should at least use `fast index creation` in 5.7

Comment: As said in the chat conversation, this helped me A LOT, but it wasn't the cause of my issues. Thanks a lot for your very valuable feedback.

Answer (score 0):

While I have no clue at what exactly happened and how to solve this issue, I have found a workaround:

- Set MySQL's `tmpdir` to a larger partition. It was too small (384M) and used to be full and block some queries. I have raised it (1.5GB)
- Store the data on a faster disk. I have stored it on a SSD, it used to be on a standard HDD

I did not reproduce either of the issues with these two modifications (the issues being the query hung and a self crash of the server).

Answer (score 0):

For the MD5 to be repeatable, `order by st.stop_sequence` should go inside the `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

`group by stops_taken` adds nothing useful.

I think your first `SELECT` can be simplified to

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        md5(group_concat(st.stop_iid)
            order by  st.stop_sequence 
           ) as stops_taken
    from  trips t
    JOIN  stop_times st ON st.trip_iid = t.id ;
```

and this might run faster.

Then, why is `trip_types` a `temporary table`?  Aren't you trying to build a permanent list of "stop list" --> "id"?

And aren't you going to have multiple trips with the same sequence of stops?  But I don't see a `DISTINCT`.  Oh, maybe that is what you are trying to do with `GROUP BY stops_taken`.  Please use `DISTINCT` for clarity.

Make the index in the tmp table

```
INDEX idx_md5 (md5_stops_taken, id)
```

This will be more efficient ("Using index").

Finally, for the `UPDATE`, use the multi-table syntax (with a `JOIN`) instead of a subquery.